# Calling Form2 from Form1 in VB6 using instances problem

Tags: c#, vb6, cefsharp

Actually I wanted to use cefsharp with my VB6 project and I am having following two problems:-

1. My project runs from let's say `form1` and I need to call `form2` where I have initialized the chromium browser using cefsharp by making use of C# class library.

Now when I call form2 from form1 like
`form2.showme`
(Where `showme` is just a custom function to set size etc) the chromium browser is able to get initialized without any issues, but when I call form2 like

```
Public ofrm2 AS form2

Public Sub function()
Set ofrm2=new form2
call ofrm2.showme
End Sub
```

then even though no error log or error of any kind is given and form2 is shown successfully, but there is no cefsharp chromium browser object on it this time.

I am also using `SetParent` and `SetWindowPos` to set up the length and width of my chromium browser in form2. I really am unable to find the issue, please suggest some fix.

2. The second problem is VB6 Editor does not allow debugging as soon as my code Initializes chromium. The only way to test the application for me was to make an **exe** and then run the application and try debugging using logs.

Edit:- ****************************************************************

My C# dll containing cefsharp packages

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name ="FullTrust")]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)] 
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IForm1
    {
        private ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //initializeChromium();
        }

        public int initializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

            if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
            {
                CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
            }
            _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://127.0.0.1:24125/ABC/DEF.html");
            _browser.RegisterJsObject("External", this);

            this.Controls.Add(_browser);

            _browser.BringToFront();
            _browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            this.Show();
            return 0;

        }
    }
```

My Form1:-

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Call launch ------ This one does not work. definition is given in my module below
'frmHTML.Show -----This one works

End Sub

Private Sub Form_UnLoad(cancel As Integer)
Set ofrmHtml = Nothing
End Sub
```

ModDec.bas:-

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long


Public ofrmHtml As frmHTML

Public Sub launch()
Set ofrmHtml = New frmHTML
Call ofrmHtml.InitChromium1


ofrmHtml.ShowMe
'call ofrmHtml.ShowMe
End Sub
```

My form2(frmHTML):-

```
Option Explicit

Public cSharpObj As New cSharp.Form1

Private Sub Form_Load()  
   'Call InitChromium1
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Sub InitChromium1()
'   On Error GoTo Err_Hndlr   

   SetParent cSharpObj.getHandle, frmHTML.hWnd
   SetWindowPos cSharpObj.getHandle, 0, 0, 0, 512, 480, 0



   Dim i As Integer
   i = -1
   i = cSharpObj.initializeChromium()

    Exit Sub
End Sub
Public Sub ShowMe()
    Call Me.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: And C# has been added here for what reason?

Comment: @Steve I have used C# to create a DLL which allows VB6 to access cefsharp and chromium

Comment: I know others have integrated CefSharp into vb6 successfully, one such project is https://github.com/javis86/cefinteropcontrol

Comment: I don't think there is enough code / detail to figure out what is different in the two scenarios. Please add more *relevant* detail.

Comment: I'd want to see the initialization code in form2, esp the contents of the `showme` function...  Especially, are there any direct references to `form2`, or perhaps some other reference that is breaking this?  Additionally, I could imagine trying a few things, like trying some of the initialization on `Form_Load()` and `Form_Activate()` or some other path, just to try to get more information about what it's actually doing, even iif they don't result in the actual fix.

Comment: @User51 Updated the code, please see if you can find some problem and help me solve the problem

Comment: @StayOnTarget Updated the code, please see if you can find some problem and help me solve the problem

Comment: The second issue, that VB6 IDE freezes when the C# code is running - as far as I know this is unavoidable. The VB6 IDE is ancient and doesn't run independently of the VB6 program itself. So if you VB6 code is blocking on something (like the C# form in this case) the IDE just will freeze / wait until control is returned to it.

Comment: Your description of the 2 scenarios - one where it works and one where it doesn't - still is not clear. What exactly is *different* between the two cases?

Comment: @StayOnTarget If I read it correctly, the difference is between using the built-in instance and creating an instance.  `Form1.showme()` uses the default instance, whereas it appears to fail when he creates a new instance in the `ofrm2` var, thus not using the built-in instance.